# Finding out what's writing to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm investigating an infinite loop where I believe something is writing to localstorage and triggering a 'storage' event listener. How can I tell what specifically is writing to local storage?

I tried adding a console.log inside of a 'storage' event listener, but this just logs the same values every time; apparently whatever is looping is writing the same value over and over again, so this doesn't help figure out what is causing the loop:

```
addEventListener('storage', () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
});
```

How can I console.log the key and value whenever something writes to localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the default javascript localStorage.setItem with a wrapper function that console.log's before calling the original function:

```
const oldSetItemFunction = window.localStorage.setItem.bind(window.localStorage);
window.localStorage.setItem = (key, value) => {
  console.log(`Setting local storage.
   - Key: ${key}
   - Value: ${value}`);
  oldSetItemFunction(key, value);
}
```

Comment: arent u getting `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at window.localStorage.setItem`?

Comment: You can also throw an error so that you can examine the stack trace, which might help depending on what sort of debugging you're trying to do. Unfortunately, it's common to see assignments to local storage using dot notation rather than `setItem`, which this approach won't intercept.

Comment: If that's an issue, you can also do `delete window.localStorage` (it doesn't clear the actual storage, don't worry) and then set `localStorage` to be your own Proxy object, allowing you to intercept anything.